# Activating Windows 7 In A Secure Environment

Tags: windows-7, intranet, activation

My company has a secure (air gapped) internal network in a secure portion of our facility. The machines in this area process data that is not meant to be exposed to the outside world so there is no internet connectivity in this environment. I am unable to bring in outside electronic devices due to our security policy.

One machine (Windows 7) is saying it needs to be activated. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you activate these with a phone call? After several failures through the regular process, I seem to remember I was offered the option to call some robot/hotline. You'ld just have to type a few series of numbers on your phone, then another few series back on the activation window, ... Let us know if this is still a valid workaround.

Comment: Not a valid work around, I am unable to take my wireless phone into the secure area and there is no landline in the room.

Comment: Huh? You don't need to take your phone anywhere near the computer to do this. You do need to be able to write something on a piece of paper and take it out of the "secure" room though.

Comment: You have "air gaped" whole network (including servers) or just that part of the network is disconnected from the Internet? If the whole network is "air gaped" then use a phone. If only that part of the network is disconnected then use proxy activation through VAMT.

Comment: The whole network is air gapped. It has it's own servers, and other equipment to handle the processing. 

I think the best course of action is to do pen/paper with a phone outside of the secure area.

Answer (score 1):

Ask whomever does your licensing, possibly your reseller, about the licensing of that host.

Read up on the [possible ways to do volume activation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/volume-activation/plan-for-volume-activation-client). MAK by phone is possible for hosts without Internet, but so are other methods.